# Other way to update doctrine's OneToMany relationship in symfony framework

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I using symfony 3.4 and doctrineORM 2.5, I have an entity called Project which contains a OneToMany relationship to other entity called Opportunity

So, in the form edit UI of Project entity I have a multiselect choices of opportunities, the user can select or deselect any opportunity in this list.

When I submit the form to ProjectController--->editAction doctrine update automatically opportunities's ArrayCollection with the new selected values, that's good :), but after persist Project object doctrine does not remove that user is deselected from the multi selection list.

```
class Project{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Module\CRMBundle\Entity\Opportunity", mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $opportunities;
}

class Opportunity{
    /**
     * @var Project
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Module\CRMBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="opportunities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_code", referencedColumnName="code")
     */
    private $project;
}
```

My solution is to reset the relationship everytime somebody edits Project like this :

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Project $project){
        $form = $this->createForm('Module\CRMBundle\Form\ProjectType', $project);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

//Get all old opportunities of this project and set their project to null
        $oldOpportunities = $em->getRepository('CRMBundle:Opportunity')->findBy(array(
            'project' => $project
        ));
        foreach ($oldOpportunities as $opportunity){
            $opportunity->setProject(null);
            $em->persist($opportunity);
        }
//If request is comming we set this project to whole opportunities
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            foreach ($project->getOpportunities() as $opportunity){
                $opportunity->setProject($project);
            }
        }

        $em->persist($project);
        $em->flush();
}
```

This solution work very well, but there is a best way to update this relationship because sometimes I have a very lot Opportunities from the owning side (Project), I think that very expensive query that doctrine will excute

Comment: `cascade={"persist"}` ? see [this](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/add-new-collection-cascade-persist)

Comment: @Cid thanks for this comment, but that's not what I looking for, this exemple explain how automatically call persist on each of the collection item by adding the option cascade={"persist"}, this is good idea only on Create mode but what I looking for is how managing the deleted items from UI because the collection will be updated when data comming and I will not be able to remove the association between the deleted item and the owner side